# cross product of vectors - distance from a line.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> I have the following question :
>   Let $A$ and $B$ be distinct points in $\mathbb R^3$. Show that the distance, d, 
>   of the point $P\in{\mathbb R^3}$, from the line through A and B is given by
>   $$d=\frac{|PA\times PB|}{|AB|}$$
>   I know 
>   $$ |PA\times PB|=|PA||PB|{\sin(\theta)}$$
>   but where to from here? I know that the line to the line connecting $A$ and 
>   $B$ is orthogonal to $AB$.

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Advanced%20Level/Point_to_line.htm

Comment: Try drawing a picture.

Comment: Think triangularly. Think of area, perpendicular height and base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $3$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ forms a plane, so you can just think of this problem as in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for simplicity. Now in the triangle $PAB$, denote the angles at each vertex $P$ $B$ by $\theta$, $\beta$ respectively. Using Sine law, we have:

$\frac{|PA \times PB|}{|AB|}=|PA||PB|\frac{\sin \theta}{|AB|}=|PB|\sin \beta=d,$ where $d$ is the distance from $P$ to $AB$. And we are done.